# CSS image is not in row. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
  page {
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
  }
  page[size="A4"] {
    width:21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
  }
  page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    min-height: 21cm;  
  }
  @media print {
    body {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    page[size="A4"] > * {
        visibility:visible;
    }
  }
```

```html
<page size="A4">
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_gujarati.png"> </div>
</page>
```

As you can see in the second row there is right side image and left part is empty. I want all images in the row. But the following condition is applied.

> 1. Height and width of the images are dynamic.
> 2. How much image will contain in the single row is also dynamic.
> 3. The width of the page is static.

How can I remove empty white space and resolve this issue?

Comment: clear your floats. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)

Comment: Are you setting widths to the image containers? If you want them all to float in one row their combined width can NOT surpass the view width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) box. And Set the `display` to `flex` with `flex-wrap:wrap`.

```css
page {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex; // updated this
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  page[size="A4"] {
    width:21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
  }
  page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    min-height: 21cm;  
  }
  @media print {
    body {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    page[size="A4"] > * {
        visibility:visible;
    }
  }
```

```html
<page size="A4">
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_gujarati.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_english.png"> </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_gujarati.png"> </div>
</page>
```

Comment: They don't stay inside of the container they're in

Comment: this makes it all 1 row... probably need `flex-wrap` set

Comment: @Sunil Garg dude problem in print can you access this URL and try to print it? https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/index.php/Barcode_printing?Barcode_id%5B%5D=5443&Quantity%5B%5D=12&Barcode_language%5B%5D=Both&Barcode_id%5B%5D=5444&Quantity%5B%5D=1&Barcode_language%5B%5D=Both&Barcode_calculation_mode=Auto&Units%5B%5D=11&Units%5B%5D=13&Language=Both You will see problem in bottom.

Comment: @shahrushabh What problem?

Comment: @shahrushabh , what is the problem, I am able to access the URL, you want to print it on one page?

Comment: Bro tries the print command and at page end, you will see the row is breaking. empty space.

Comment: And no I don't want to print it on one page just look at last row of the first page. You will understand the issue. Please help me.

Comment: I am trying will let you know soon

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flexbox` here. Apply `display: flex` to `page[size="A4"]` element.

And also remove `float: left` inline style. No need here.

```css
page {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  min-height: 29.7cm;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  min-height: 21cm;
}

@media print {
  body {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  page[size="A4"]>* {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<page size="A4">
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_gujarati.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_english.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_gujarati.png"> </div>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your example to work with `Bootstrap v4`.

I used `row` class to create a row and `col-md-3` class to allow 4 images per row.

> Bootstrap only supports up to *12 columns in a row*. E.g `4 images = 12
>   / 4` which gives you `col-*-3`

Then I gave `.col-md-3 img` properties: `width: 100%`, `height: 100%`

**HTML**

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<page size="A4">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</page>
```

**CSS**

---

```
page {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  min-height: 29.7cm;
}

page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  min-height: 21cm;
}

@media print {
  body {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  page[size="A4"]>* {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.col-md-3 img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

Here's JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezcrtn22/2/

Comment: You may also clear the gutters but adding a `nogutter` class to the `row` div. `.nogutter { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; }`

Answer (score -2):

Giving all your divs a fixed height, solves the problem (this height should be the maximum of all the images). Even better would be a resizing of the images towards a fixed height, this prevents the images from being cut of.

Actually I don't see any need for divs around the images you could simply omit them.

```css
  page {
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
  }
  page[size="A4"] {
    width:21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
  }
  page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    min-height: 21cm;  
  }
  @media print {
    body {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    page[size="A4"] > * {
        visibility:visible;
    }
  }
page img {
  height: 170px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<page size="A4">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/11_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_gujarati.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_english.png">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/710451/13_gujarati.png">
</page>
```